# Solve of $y''-2y'+y=\frac{3e^t}{1+t^2}+7$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following DE $y''-2y'+y=\frac{3e^t}{1+t^2}+7$

I can solve for the homogeneous equation, that isn't a problem. However, I don't know how to approach the particular solution. I would try the method of undetermined coefficients but I don't know how to apply it to rational functions.

Comment: Did you try the "variation of the constants"-method ?

Comment: I don't think I remember that method. Is that the one where you are given a solution say, y1 and you let v(x)=(y1)*c(X) be another solution and then solve for v(x)?

Comment: Yes, but here it is a bit more complicated because you have two linear independent solutions.

Comment: "Undetermined coefficients" is another expression for this method. So you were on the right track. Where did you get stuck ?

Comment: I got stuck when it came to deciding how to set up my particular solution. I would know how to set it up if the right hand side was $sin(t)$ or something simpler like only an exponential function.

Comment: Please show us how far you got.

Comment: Wolfram gives the solution $$y(t)=c_1e^t+c_2e^tt-\frac{3}{2}e^tln(t^2+1)+3e^tt\ arctan(t)+7$$

Comment: But I have no access to the step-by-step-solution.

Comment: I just reviewed variation of parameters and I think I can solve this now, thank you

Comment: This may give you a start: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/first-order-linear-odes/MIT18_03SCF11_s4_5text.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Using the variation of parameters, the particular solution is given by the linear combination
\begin{equation*}
x_p(t)=u_1(t)x_{i_1}(t)+u_2(t)x_{i_2}(t)
\end{equation*}
with $x_{i_1}(t)=e^2,~x_{i_2}(t)=e^tt$ (these are found when finding the complementary solution), and
\begin{equation*}
u_1(t)=-\int \frac{f(t)x_{i_2}(t)}{W(t)}dt,~u_2(t)=\int \frac{f(t)x_{i_1}(t)}{W(t)}dt
\end{equation*}
for $f(t)=\frac{3e^t}{t^2+1}+7$ and $W$ is the Wronskian.